# How to remove warning regarding the use of status code 200 with flashing in Play 2.3.7?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have just updated my [play-example-form](http://ics-software-engineering.github.io/play-example-form/) application to work with Play 2.3.7.  It went very smoothly, but now when I run the application I get the following warning in my console:

```
[warn] play - You are using status code '200' with flashing, which should only be used with a redirect status!
```

It seems to me that I need to replace the use of "ok" in my controller with something else, but (for example) just substituting "redirect" does not work. Here's the [controller code with relevant lines highlighted](https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/play-example-form/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java#L66-71).

How should I fix this, or is this just a spurious warning that I can ignore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you would only use flash data with redirects, where you would otherwise not be able to render any data until the next request. And after that, the data is gone. For example, when the user logs out of my application, I might redirect them back to the login page, with a flash message saying "Please login again..". The warning for non-redirect status codes is to let you know that the data will be gone if say, the user clicks a link from the rendered page.

I believe technically the flash data will still be picked up by your rendered view (an implicit `Request` parameter in the view might be required). Even so, it would be better practice to use a `message: String` parameter for the view you're passing the message to, rather than relying on `Flash`, which is meant for something else. And since it seems that you *do* want to render a view only, there's no reason to switch to a redirect.

For example:

```
@(studentForm: Form[views.formdata.StudentFormData],
  hobbies: Map[String,Boolean],
  levels: List[String],
  gpa: Map[String,Boolean],
  majors: Map[String,Boolean],
  message: String)
```

...

```
  Student student = Student.makeInstance(formData.get());

  return ok(Index.render(formData,
    Hobby.makeHobbyMap(formData.get()),
    GradeLevel.getNameList(),
    GradePointAverage.makeGPAMap(formData.get()),
    Major.makeMajorMap(formData.get()),
    "Student instance created/edited: " + student
  ));
```

Comment: Very helpful reply. Thank you for the quick response!